# Why are the links in a table referencing a class taking the style of the links in the main <body> tag?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm attempting to format links in a table. I've already specified the default format for links inside the `<body>` tag. They appear correctly.Can someone point out why the following CSS would format all the links on the page (including those inside a table tagged with `<table class="links"></table>`) as in the `<body>` tag?  I've already read a number of posts on this site and various others about using CSS to format objects inside tags (using classes), but I think there's some other fundamental thing I'm missing.

```
body
{
    background-color:#800000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font:14px arial,sans-serif;
}
body a:link
{
    color:#FFFFFF; /* unvisited link */
    text-decoration:underline;
    font:11px arial,sans-serif;
}
body a:visited
{
    color:#FFFFFF; /* visited link */
    text-decoration:underline;
    font:11px arial,sans-serif;
}
body a:hover
{
    color:#FFFFFF; /* mouse over link */
    text-decoration:none;
    font:11px arial,sans-serif;
}
body a:active
{
    color:#FFFFFF; /* selected link */ 
    text-decoration:none;
    font:11px arial,sans-serif;
}

table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    background-color:#DDDDDD;
    color:#000000;
    font:14px arial,sans-serif;
}
table, td, th
{
    border:1px solid black;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
td.header
{
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
tr.header
{
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
table.links a:link
{
    color:#000000; /* unvisited link */
    text-decoration:underline;
    font:14px arial,sans-serif;
}
table.links a:visited
{
    color:#000000; /* visited link */
    text-decoration:underline;
    font:14px arial,sans-serif;
}
table.links a:hover
{
    color:#000000; /* mouse over link */
    text-decoration:none;
    font:14px arial,sans-serif;
}
table.links a:active
{
    color:#000000; /* selected link */ 
    text-decoration:none;
    font:14px arial,sans-serif;
}
```

EDIT: Here's the source that made use of the stylesheet.

```
<?php
    include "../Core/Debug_Start.php";
    include "../Core/Database.php";
    Debug::Out( "Running 'Boat/UpdateBlades.php'" );
    include "User.php";
    include "Blades.php";

    session_start();
    if( !Users::IsUserLoggedIn() )
        header( "location:../index.php" );
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="../Styles/Damflask/Style_Damflask.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // returns a full list of all blade sets
    $aBladeSets = Blades::GetAllBladeSets( $database );
    $iNumBladeSets = count( $aBladeSets );
    if( $iNumBladeSets == 0 )
        return;
    $iNumRows = $iNumBladeSets + 1;

    // create the table
    echo( "<table class=\"links\" align=\"center\">" );
    for( $iRowIndex = 0; $iRowIndex < $iNumRows; $iRowIndex++ )
    {
        echo( "<tr>" );
        if( $iRowIndex == 0 )
        {
            // NAME
            echo( "<td class=\"header\">NAME</td>" );

            // AVAILABLE
            echo( "<td class=\"header\">AVAILABLE</td>" );

            // ADDITIONAL INFO
            echo( "<td class=\"header\">INFO</td>" );

            // EDIT / DELETE
            echo( "<td class=\"header\" colspan=\"2\"></td>" );
        }
        else
        {
            // display the blade set
            $iBladeSetIndex = $iRowIndex - 1;
            $bladeSet = $aBladeSets[ $iBladeSetIndex ];

            // NAME
            echo( "<td>" . $bladeSet->GetName() . "</td>" );

            // AVAILABLE
            echo( "<td>" );
            if( $bladeSet->IsAvailable() )
                echo( "Yes" );
            else
                echo( "No" );
            echo( "</td>" );

            // ADDITIONAL INFO
            echo( "<td>" . $bladeSet->GetAdditionalInfo() . "</td>" );

            // EDIT
            echo( "<td><a class=\"tablelink\" href=\"UpdateBlades.php?BladesID=" . $bladeSet->GetID() . "\">EDIT</a></td>" );

            // DELETE
            echo( "<td><a class=\"tablelink\" href=\"DeleteBladeSet.php?BladesID=" . $bladeSet->GetID() . "\">DELETE</a></td>" );
        }
        echo( "</tr>" );
    }
    echo( "<tr><td colspan=\"5\"><a href=\"AddBlades.php\">ADD A NEW BLADE SET</a></td></tr>" );
    echo( "</table>" );

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $database->CloseConnection();
    include "../Core/Debug_End.php"
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your table have a class on it?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML markup, too.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to prefix your normal `a` selectors with `body`.  It's a given that every `a` tag will be a descendant of `body`, you're adding unnecessary specificity.  You've also defined way more properties than you need (font, color, etc.) instead of relying on inheritance/cascading.

Comment: Cinnamon, can you elaborate on your comment: "... defined more properties than you need instead of relying on inheritance/cascading." I'm only using what I'm aware of. Can you point me to a more appropriate way of doing whatever I could do better? (Ideally a "best practice").

Comment: Please post your generated HTML, not the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Just realised (4 months on) that I hadn't closed this question. As it turns out, there's a space between the body{} and table{} tags:

```
body a:active
{
    color:#FFFFFF; /* selected link */ 
    text-decoration:none;
    font:11px arial,sans-serif;
}
 <--- A space.
table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    background-color:#DDDDDD;
    color:#000000;
    font:14px arial,sans-serif;
}
```

By removing the space, it works as intended.

Answer (score -1):

Your not targeting them correctly in your CSS thats why!

```
table.links .tablelink {
 STYLES HERE
}
```

Would be the correct way to target them with your current markup, by using your:

```
table.links a:link {
```

You dont need the class name of .tablelink if you going to target the links the way you are, its just extra markup, you would just need:

The benefit of using the .tablelink class is all you need in the CSS to style those links is:

```
.tablelink {
STYLES HERE
}
```

You also dont need to use:

```
table.links {
```

You can just use:

```
.links {
```

Comment: `table.links a` will target every `a` element that is a child of a table element with class `links`. You are confusing ` ` with `>` here.